# Comparing entity instances in PonyORM

Tags: ponyorm

I am trying to compare PonyORM entity instances for identity/equality. Consider the following code, using the `estore` example database:

```python
from pony.orm import *
from pony.orm.examples.estore import *

# Test 1
with db_session:
    a = Customer[1]
    b = Customer[1]
print(a is b, a == b)    # True True

# Test 2
with db_session:
    a = Customer[1]
with db_session:
    b = Customer[1]
print(a is b, a == b)    # False False
```

Entities with the same primary key test as identical and equal if and only if retrieved in the same `db_session`.

1. What is the rationale behind this behaviour? (From the docs: *If object   with the specified primary key was already loaded into the db_session() cache, Pony returns the object from the cache without sending a query to the database.* This explains the result of the identity test. I would still expect to see equality in both test 1 and 2.)
2. What is the recommended way to test for equality (other than comparing primary keys)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the rationale behind this behaviour?

Originally Pony expects you to work with objects inside `db_session` only. So - you should not use these objects once `db_session` is over. Why is this - you can treat `db_session` as a transaction. So if you use two different `db_sessions` you use different transactions and it means there is no guarantee that these 2 objects are logically consistent.

Why Pony allows you to use objects after `db_session`? Because some of developers want to separate application layer from the database layer and render HTML templates after `db_session` is over.

Actually Pony thinks that the right way is to render templates inside `db_session` but is was too demanded, so Pony became to allow it. But anyway mixing objects from two other `db_sessions` is completely wrong way, and Pony don't want you to do it.

> What is the recommended way to test for equality?

If you still want to compare objects from different db_sessions I'd recommend you to use function like this

```
def equals(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, pony.orm.core.Entity):
        return type(a) == type(b) and a.get_pk() == b.get_pk()
    return a == b

with db_session:
    a = Customer[1]
with db_session:
    b = Customer[1]
print(a is b, a == b, equals(a, b))    # False, False, True
```